# Snow Leopard 10.6.3 Freezes Frequently

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook

Snow Leopard 10.6.3 on my Macbook Pro freezes quite frequently now. It freezes for few seconds and then works fine. During that time trackpad does not work and keyboard works partially (missing keystrokes while I type).

Initially it was once or twice in a day but now it has become quite frequent. Is somebody else facing similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a pretty common problem. Try reinstalling 10.6 and then upgrading to 10.6.2 but DON'T install 10.6.3 until Apple gets around to fixing the problem (probably in 10.6.4).

Answer (score 0):

You're problem could originate from so many things, it's really unlikely that you'll get an answer that solves your problem.

I suggest booting from an [Ubuntu CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download) just to see if it's a hardware or a software issue.

In case of a hardware issue, turn it in to repair.

In case of a software issue, the simplest might be to [make a backup](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427). Reinstall Mac OS X and use the [Migration Assistent](http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/migration.html) to copy all your previous data to the new system.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed.  I have four macs, three of which I had to move back to 10.6.2 in exactly the way described (reapplying the 10.6.3 combo update doesn't help).  Macbookpro and two minis - different generations - both kept locking up - in the case of the macbookpro within 10 minutes or so of starting work, every time).  Went back to 10.6.2 and all was fine.  Not a hardware issue.  Oh, the mac that wasn't affected is a mac pro desktop.  No idea why, as all the applications software is the same on each machine.

Waiting for 10.6.4 before I'll let software update near them again :^).

Answer (score 0):

Bad fonts are often the cause of otherwise unexplainable behaviour. Use Font Book to verify your fonts and disable any that don't pass.